# Finding residues of a sum in paper by Hitchen

Tags: real-analysis, zeta-functions

I am reading Nigel Hitchin's paper on *Harmonic spinors* [Adv. Math.  14 (1974) 1-55].  On p 34  he defines a function
$$
f(s)= 
\sum_{p,q\in{\mathbb Z}_+ }(p+q)(4pq \lambda^2 +(p-q)^2)^{-s}.
$$
The series converges absolutely for $s>3/2$, and he says "Computing the residues at $s=1/2$, $s=3/2$ we finally....". I have no idea how to compute these residues.  Can anyone suggest a suitable method for this and related sums?

The sum is over positive integers only, so it does  not appear to be an Epstein zeta function.